# Wifi adapter not found on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth

I know this question has been asked a lot, but none of the answers i have found have helped me.

I have a HP laptop that I have put Ubuntu 17.10 on and ever since the first boot it could not find any wifi or bluetooth adapters. I have tried to install Realtek drivers but it has not worked. My Wifi and Bluetooth adapters are built-in.

when I run `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` the output is

```
    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: wl
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:832c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74325/discussion-on-question-by-nyle-cohen-wifi-adapter-not-found-on-ubuntu-17-10).